# Options to use iPad as remote photo viewing client

Tags: ipad, photos, sharing, nas, network

As it says [here](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=280), I can use an iPad as a remote photo vieing client if I buy the WD My Book Live NAS. But I have an old [NAS](http://www.planex.net/product/nas/nas-01g.htm) already and I wonder if there are any generic iPad apps that give similar function, but without restriction on a specific NAS?

Thanks.

Comment: is your main computer a Mac or PC? I ask because some of these kinds of apps rely on a helper app that runs on the computer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Remiew](http://remiew.com/)

I can view any photo I saved on my PC from iPad as it gives full control on folder navigation, i.e. I can browse all folders of my pc without any restrictions.

One restriction it that it shows images only, no other file types are shown.

It was a bit tricky to set it up at first, but it works fine for me and it's free.

Comment: Note, that security of this app is questionable. You are not required and cannot provide any username / password and you get unrestricted full access immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a free cloud storage solution such as [dropbox.com](http://dropbox.com) or [box.net](http://box.net). For example, you can install the Dropbox application on any of your PCs / Macs, and upload images to a folder. On your iPad, download the Dropbox app and you will see those files show up.

Those solutions serve as an online NAS and it is free to use if you only use <1-2GB of storage space. Many other apps also support them so you can transfer files from and to your iPad.

Comment: What about over a local LAN?

Answer (score 1):

Soon, with iOS 5, the new 'Photostream' feature will more than likely fill this need for you:

http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html

Answer (score 0):

[This app](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/06/23/view-your-iphoto-library-from-your-ipad/) claims to view iPhoto libraries remotely, and [this discussion](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1042758) suggests Zumocast and Plex for doing the same. It also implies Zumocast can show folders full of files.

Several sites suggest publishing your photo folders as a website in Apache and browsing them in Safari on the iPad, with or without some kind of pleasant web front-end / gallery site.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Cinq](http://cinq.tunaverse.com/) for this, it works fine on iPad and iPhone. You'll need to run the helper app on a Mac or PC, and it will drag the photos from your hard drive or NAS and display them.

It also allows you to send your photos wirelessly from your iPhone (and i guess iPad 2) to your Mac or PC.

[Zumocast](http://www.zumocast.com/) does something similar, but i preferred Cinq. It seems that Zumocast has suspended downloads for the moment, not sure what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

AirPhotoViewer Can lets you view photo form your pc over wifi with out sync  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airphotoviewer/id524118762?ls=1&mt=8